# Stereo calibration, the extrinsic parameters to tf?

Tags: calibration, stereo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have two identical RGB cameras fixed to a rigid structure. They are synchronized by it's [own node](http://wiki.ros.org/ueye_cam). Each camera is rotated clock-wise and counter clock-wise (due to where the usb connector is mounted on the camera's pcb). Therefore, I have rotated the images first and then publish them and use them for calibration and stereo_proc.

I've done the stereo calibration and managed to have the stereo_proc node working with help I got from [this answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/222218/completely-black-rectified-images-kind-of-solve/) (mine as well, I didn't know if I should have opened a new question or not....but as it's a different topic I did).

I have successfully calibrated the cameras and obtained these left.yaml and right.yaml

left.yaml

```
image_width: 512
image_height: 512
camera_name: stereo/left
camera_matrix:
  rows: 3
  cols: 3
  data: [2344.331957, 0, 337.706086, 0, 2357.396758, 82.47229799999999, 0, 0, 1]
distortion_model: plumb_bob
distortion_coefficients:
  rows: 1
  cols: 5
  data: [-0.6336689999999999, 3.019293, 0.013087, 0.008579, 0]
rectification_matrix:
  rows: 3
  cols: 3
  data: [0.9948509999999999, -0.002312, 0.101323, 0.002147, 0.999996, 0.001734, -0.101327, -0.001507, 0.994852]
projection_matrix:
  rows: 3
  cols: 4
  data: [4243.110203, 0, 70.32520700000001, 0, 0, 4243.110203, 75.543232, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

right.yaml

```
image_width: 512
image_height: 512
camera_name: stereo/right
camera_matrix:
  rows: 3
  cols: 3
  data: [2346.048386, 0, 312.031898, 0, 2349.95312, 70.149203, 0, 0, 1]
distortion_model: plumb_bob
distortion_coefficients:
  rows: 1
  cols: 5
  data: [-0.604228, 1.382571, 0.015306, 0.004007, 0]
rectification_matrix:
  rows: 3
  cols: 3
  data: [0.993127, -0.003312, 0.116991, 0.003502, 0.9999929999999999, -0.00142, -0.116986, 0.00182, 0.9931319999999999]
projection_matrix:
  rows: 3
  cols: 4
  data: [4243.110203, 0, 70.32520700000001, -4319.654554, 0, 4243.110203, 75.543232, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

So with {left, right}/{image_raw, camera_info} I can obtain the rectified images and disparity map (even though not so good at the moment, therefore the other question) but that would concern the **intrinsic** parameters.

What about the ***extrinsic*** parameters? How do I extract them from camera_info and publish them to tf?. The stereo_calibration tutorial does not mention any of this...is it because I have to do something else? Such as use the [industrial_extrinsic_cal node](http://wiki.ros.org/industrial_extrinsic_cal)?

Thank you for the help.

EDIT 1: The extrinsic parameters that I mean are the rotation and translation from one camera to another as I want to do "pixel" triangulation (e.g: Specify in x,y,z (from left camera, as stereo_proc does with the pointcloud) the position of a pixel (u,v) in left image). So, i neet the relative position between the two cameras within the stereo pair as I'll know the transformation between base_link and the left camera in my robot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224342/stereo-calibration,-the-extrinsic-parameters-to-tf?/) by [Ariel](https://answers.ros.org/users/23277/ariel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2016-01-18

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dimitri Schachmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/22775/dimitri-schachmann/) on 2016-01-18**:
And please add whether you are interested in the extrinsic calibration with respect to some world frame, or between the two cameras.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**extrinsic** with respect to **what**? `sensor_msgs::CameraInfo` does not contain any information about the extrinsic calibration (a.k.a. location with respect to some world frame) of the stereo **pair**. In ROS this information is stored only in `tf`.

When you publish your `camera_info`, it is up to you to also publish according `tf` information (if you need it), but note that for stereo cameras one usually needs only the reference frame of the left camera, which is then assumed for the whole stereo pair. That's how `stereo_image_proc` expects it to be, for example.

---

If you mean the relative position of the two cameras within the stereo pair, then it's implicitly encoded in the rectification matrix and the projection matrix. **R** and **P** in `CameraInfo.

By inspecting [the implementation](https://github.com/strawlab/vision_opencv/tree/master/image_geometry/include/image_geometry) you will see, that all that is needed for stereo matching, is the rectification matrix (**R**) and the baseline (which is computed from **P** by `-right_.Tx() / right_.fx();` where `right_` is the `CameraInfo` from the right camera.)

---

Originally posted by [Dimitri Schachmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/22775/dimitri-schachmann/) with karma: 789 on 2016-01-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ariel](https://answers.ros.org/users/23277/ariel/) on 2016-01-18**:
So I can physically measure the baseline=10cm. Therefore, if I use the values from right P I should get the same number (4319.6/4243.1=1.01). Therefore, I can check that the calibration is not correct? BTW, right_.fx is also from P, right? Not from K? Shouldn't it be fx'() then?

**Comment by [Dimitri Schachmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/22775/dimitri-schachmann/) on 2016-01-19**:
I must admit I am currently unable to wrap my head around the math, but is `StereoCameraModel::projectDisparityTo3d` perhaps what you need? See in https://github.com/strawlab/vision_opencv/blob/master/image_geometry/src/stereo_camera_model.cpp

**Comment by [Ariel](https://answers.ros.org/users/23277/ariel/) on 2016-01-19**:
If I understood correctly, with projectDisparityTo3d I the left{u,v} pixel that I want the 3d coordinate, the value of that pixel (same u,v?) in the disparity image and I'll get the xyz point. Is that correct?

**Comment by [Dimitri Schachmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/22775/dimitri-schachmann/) on 2016-01-19**:
I must admit I'm a bit confused myself but yes: you give it pixel coordinates `uv` (of the left camera) and a disparity and it gives you 3D coordinates XYZ of that thing that you see at `uv` in the reference frame of the left camera.

**Comment by [Ariel](https://answers.ros.org/users/23277/ariel/) on 2016-01-19**:
What's making you a bit confused? I'll give it a try a check how things work....but based on my first comment here, there is something wrong with the calibration as the baseline gives me 1.01 meters rather than 0.1 meters.....

**Comment by [Ariel](https://answers.ros.org/users/23277/ariel/) on 2016-01-20**:
One thing that I still don't understand is the *double* disparity variable. I have three values for each pixel in the disparity topic (R,G,B) and I need one value for the projectDisparityTo3d function. How does that work?

**Comment by [Dimitri Schachmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/22775/dimitri-schachmann/) on 2016-01-20**:
Disparity images must have only one channel! It makes no sense for them to have three channels. Where do you get your `stereo_msgs/DisparityImage` from? What does `msg.image.encoding` contain?

**Comment by [Ariel](https://answers.ros.org/users/23277/ariel/) on 2016-01-20**:
My mistake....the encoding is 32FC1. I still cannot obtain a decent disparity image.....When I use max resolution (1280x1024) rather than 30fps that I get from the raw data from the cameras, the disparity images is ~1fps....could it be some bottleneck in stereo_image_proc?

**Comment by [Dimitri Schachmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/22775/dimitri-schachmann/) on 2016-01-20**:
Do the disparity images, even though 1fps, look sensible? If not, then your calibration is most probably wrong. What does `htop` say about your CPU usage, how much is stereo_image_proc taking up?

**Comment by [Dimitri Schachmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/22775/dimitri-schachmann/) on 2016-01-20**:
I also suggest the following cheap check: display left/image_rect and right/image_rect side by side and check whether they look rectified as one would expect. (i.e. same features on same pixel row and in the right image further to the left).

**Comment by [Ariel](https://answers.ros.org/users/23277/ariel/) on 2016-01-20**:
The disparity images (in that example is with smaller resolution and calibrated at that resolution) looks [like this](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=316kun9&s=9#.Vp9bil7L_7A).I'm still not sure about whether rotating the images is correct for calibration,but if I don't do it I get black rect'd imgs

**Comment by [Ariel](https://answers.ros.org/users/23277/ariel/) on 2016-01-20**:
[Here](http://i63.tinypic.com/35n7j9j.png) is a screenshot of the disparity image at max res (with proper calibration) and htop on the side.

**Comment by [Dimitri Schachmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/22775/dimitri-schachmann/) on 2016-01-20**:
Well can not see anything wrong in the rectified images, but the disparity image is completely wrong. Those specs are just accidental matches. Why and how do you rotate the images? And yes stereo_image_proc gives you a lot of load on the CPU, but I'm surprised that it's that much!

**Comment by [Ariel](https://answers.ros.org/users/23277/ariel/) on 2016-01-20**:
I tested again and changed the disparity_range to a much bigger value and I started getting something different as shown [here](http://i66.tinypic.com/2amh3o.png) but there is still a lot of grey areas. The images seem to be well rectified.

**Comment by [Ariel](https://answers.ros.org/users/23277/ariel/) on 2016-01-20**:
[Here](http://i67.tinypic.com/2j284tl.jpg) you can see at the top the raw images (cameras are fixed and rotated due to their usb connector...). At the bottom are the rotated images using cv::transpose and cv::flip(other node) I rotated the image because the rectified images were completely black

**Comment by [Dimitri Schachmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/22775/dimitri-schachmann/) on 2016-01-20**:
mmh. I'm afraid I'm out of ideas for now...

**Comment by [Ariel](https://answers.ros.org/users/23277/ariel/) on 2016-01-20**:
Would it be worth it to implement the [opencv calibration](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html) myself? Would I have different results? This way I could also have all the extrinsic parameters....but would I get dif result than with ros calib?

**Comment by [Ariel](https://answers.ros.org/users/23277/ariel/) on 2016-01-21**:
I checked that I put the wrong value for the square size when calibrating. I fixed it, **didn't** rotate the images and these are the [rectified images](http://i66.tinypic.com/23r8eqa.png). The image is much smaller. The [disparity](http://i68.tinypic.com/w7j2c0.png) is still a mess.

**Comment by [Dimitri Schachmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/22775/dimitri-schachmann/) on 2016-01-21**:
your image is quite homogeneous, try to hang something with "features" on the wall.

**Comment by [Ariel](https://answers.ros.org/users/23277/ariel/) on 2016-01-22**:
I changed sides and now I have more things in the scene: [rectified](http://i63.tinypic.com/apbfpu.png) [disparity](http://i64.tinypic.com/2lmt1es.png) [rviz](http://i63.tinypic.com/9kqkh5.png). There is something in the disparity but in rviz I cannot see anything....

**Comment by [Ariel](https://answers.ros.org/users/23277/ariel/) on 2016-01-22**:
I have just re-done the calibration and checked the epi value afterwards and it averages 0.45.......this should be way smaller, right?

**Comment by [Dimitri Schachmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/22775/dimitri-schachmann/) on 2016-01-22**:
perhaps you could record a (very) short bagfile with your data and upload it somewhere?

**Comment by [Ariel](https://answers.ros.org/users/23277/ariel/) on 2016-01-22**:
which topics? image_raw, camera_info? [here it is](https://cloud.laas.fr/index.php/s/U6h69ceFIYDmUxF)

**Comment by [Ariel](https://answers.ros.org/users/23277/ariel/) on 2016-01-25**:
I checked the code and even though translation vector and rotation matrix are not saved, they are printed on the terminal when the calibration is done. These are the R and T from cv::stereoCalibrate. I still cannot get a good disparity image...

**Comment by [ducnan](https://answers.ros.org/users/50519/ducnan/) on 2020-02-11**:
So I am also trying to get the baseline of the stereo camera. Which one is the right._Tx()? Is it the first element in the self.T matrix? And as for the right.fx(), is it the first element of the projection matrix for the right camera?